# How to reorder jquery UI tabs using $.fn.tabs and underscorejs _.wrap function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, underscore.js

I am trying to recorder jquery tabs in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vF5kN5?p=preview) using jQuery UI $fn.tabs, I will be having the tabs to reorder declared in this function, The code snippet is below, I have used [underscorejs wrap](http://underscorejs.org/#wrap) function to do it

```
$.fn.tabs = _.wrap( $.fn.tabs, function extendTabs( org, arguments ) {

        var movObject =  {"name": "fragment-3", "nextSibling": "fragment-2"}; 
        console.log( "calling tabs", this, arguments );
        // perform reordering here if needed

        var listItemTobeMoved = $("li[xe-for-section="+movObject.nextSibling+"]");
        var listItemTo = $("li[xe-for-section="+movObject.name+"]");

        listItemTo.insertBefore(listItemTobeMoved);

        org.apply( this, arguments );
    });


<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li xe-for-section="fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1" xe-section ="fragment-1">
    Tab 1
  </div> 
  <div id="fragment-2" xe-section="fragment-2">
    Tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3" xe-section="fragment-3">
    Tab 3
  </div>
</div>
```

The initialization of tab works fine with the below code

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

But when i pass the extra arguments, its failing to initialize and throwing an error like below:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs("select", 3);
```

ERROR:

*Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong typescript.js:12 extendTabsunderscore.js:697 (anonymous function)(index):37 (anonymous function)*

Basically the selecting of tab item fails, How to handle this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a couple issues when taking a look at the plnkr:

First, the option you pass to initialize the selected tab in version 1.11.2 of jquery UI is slightly different. It should be like:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({active: 2});
```

as seen in the docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

And then second, I think the wrap approach is very clever, but when using wrap, the second parameter (the wrapper function) does not take the same arguments that the wrapped function takes, but rather takes a single argument that **is** the wrapped function. By changing the wrap to this...

```
$.fn.tabs = _.wrap($.fn.tabs, function expandTabs(func) {
    //console.log( "calling tabs", this, arguments );
    // perform reordering here if needed
    var movObject = { "name": "fragment-3", "nextSibling": "fragment-2" };
    console.log("calling tabs", this, arguments);
    // perform reordering here if needed

    var listItemTobeMoved = $("li[xe-for-section=" + movObject.nextSibling + "]");
    var listItemTo = $("li[xe-for-section=" + movObject.name + "]");

    listItemTo.insertBefore(listItemTobeMoved);
    console.log(arguments);
    func.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

...as well as changing the initialization line mentioned above, I was able to get the desired functionality.

Also, I needed to add a reference to underscore in the plnkr in the index file:

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```